# Confusion regarding descendant axis and '//'

Tags: xml, xpath

Structure of a document:

```
<program>
 <projectionDay>
   <projection/>
   <projection/>
 </projectionDay>
 <projectionDay>
   <projection/>
   <projection/>
 </projectionDay>
</program>
```

I want to select the first and last projection ( across the whole document).

This returns it:

```
/descendant::projection[position() = 1 or position() = last()]
```

This returns first and last within a *projectionDay*

```
//projection[position() = 1 or position() = last()]
```

Why is that so?

Comment: The `//` selects all matching nodes from the current node. Are you running that xpath query from a `<projectionDay>` node or from the root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first query using `descendant` fetches all `<projection/>` elements, then filters this result set for the first and last element:

```
/descendant::projection[position() = 1 or position() = last()]
```

`//` is an abbreviation for `/descendant-or-self::*/`. So your second query actually means

```
/descendant-or-self::*/projection[position() = 1 or position() = last()]
```

which looks into all elements (here: each `<projectionDay/>`, and returns the first and last `<projection/>` element *inside this element*.

---

To return the first and last element over all `<projeectionDay/>`s, put everything before the predicate into parentheses:

```
(/descendant-or-self::*/projection)[position() = 1 or position() = last()]
```

or abbreviated:

```
(//projection)[position() = 1 or position() = last()]
```